# comparison between the values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as

[image]

I want to filter get percent change and total change between the different quarters for YoY.

[image]

I am not sure how can i start this in python, any help will be appreciated.

Considering i have many parameters for Name. i need to use the group by filter for each KPI, YEAR and Quarter, i tried

```
d2['d'] = d2.groupby(['KPI', 'Quarter', ])['Number'].apply( lambda x: (x - x.shift(4))/x  )
```

Comment: Is possible convert pictures to text for copy data samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series,pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) per groups, multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) and if necessary [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
d2['Percent Change'] = (d2.groupby(['KPI', 'Quarter'])['Number']
                          .transform(pd.Series.pct_change)
                          .mul(100)
                          .round())
```

For total change add [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

```
d2['Total Change'] = d2['Number'].pct_change().cumsum().mul(100).round().fillna(0)
```